# how to fix: Component ClassOverallPerComponent is not part of any NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular6

i'm getting an error: **

> Component ClassOverallPerComponent is not part of any NgModule or the
>   module has not been imported into your module.

**
while compiling an angular project

I have only app.module in my project (not created another one)

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {appRouting} from './appRouting';
import {FormsModule }from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ClassOverallPerComponent } from './components/users/class-overall-per/class-overall-per.component';

//service:
import {StudentOverallPService}from './services/student-overall-p.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ClassOverallPerComponent
  ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule,HttpClientModule,RouterModule.forRoot(appRouting, {enableTracing: true}) ],
  providers: [StudentOverallPService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

appRouting :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { ClassOverallPerComponent } from './components/Users/class-overall-per/class-overall-per.component';
import { PersonalDetailsComponent } from './components/Users/personal-details/personal-details.component';

export const appRouting = [
    { path: '',  redirectTo: "personalDetails", pathMatch:'full'},//anoter components
    { path: 'ClassOverallPer', component :ClassOverallPerComponent }}]
```

ClassOverallPerComponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OverAllPer } from 'src/app/classes/OverAllPer';
import { StudentPerformances,EditStudentPerformances,PerformanceStud} from'../../../classes/StudentsOverallP';
import { StudentOverallPService } from 'src/app/services/student-overall-p.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-class-overall-per',
  templateUrl: './class-overall-per.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./class-overall-per.component.css']
})
export class ClassOverallPerComponent implements OnInit 
{
 constructor(private StudentOverallPSer: StudentOverallPService ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    debugger
   }
}
```

StudentOverallPService :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EditStudentPerformances } from '../classes/StudentsOverallP';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StudentOverallPService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  editStudentsPerformances(editStudAndOverallP:EditStudentPerformances)
  {
  }
}
```

i just wish the code running with no errors

Comment: The code seems ok, so the template can be wrong. If you use ngif or so, you should also import the commonmodule from angular/core.

Comment: my version doesn't need that import, thanks